# How to limit selection via first letter of the option in mat select

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular9

I have a mat-select select box which has options as below
`[{   label: Excellent, keyCode:A, id:1 }, { label:Very Good, keyCode:B, id:2 }, { label:Bad, keyCode:C id:3 }, ]`

The selection of the options should be based on **only the** **keyCode**. The problem is that the interface seems to allow both the short cut key and the first letter of the option labels as short cut options. Currently, the selection is implemented by a function call onKeyPressed on (keydown) of the mat-select. Is there anything possible to stop the selection via the first letter of the option labels. Thanks in advance.

material version : @angular/material": "^9.2.4",
angular : 9

Comment: Please share a minimal working StackBlitz to understand your implementation and reply on it.

Comment: You could try adding a zero width non joiner `&zwnj;` where you render the option e.g. `<mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">&zwnj;{{option.label}}</mat-option>` This should then prevent the default select behaviour where pressing the first letter selects the option